# How can I count repetitions in determinate day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

```
cpf  day  startdate              enddate
1234  1   08/01/2018 12:50:0     08/01/2018 15:30:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:30:0     08/01/2018 15:40:0
1234  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 20:20:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0
1234  2   08/02/2018 22:50:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0
1235  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
5212  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0
```

I need to calculate conversation time of cpf column in one day. For example, the first cpf is 1234, so in day 1 this cpf initiate a conversation on 08/01/2018 12:50:0 and the end of conversation was 08/01/2018 15:50:0, what I need is exactly this substraction about enddate - startdate, but disconsidering middle of table like 1234 have in 08/01/2018 three conversations, the subtraction is about first hour of first conversation subtract last hour of last conversation. How can I do this?

```
  cpf  day  startdate              enddate              Time_Conversation
    1234  1   08/01/2018 12:50:0     08/01/2018 15:30:0         3:00:0
    1234  1   08/01/2018 14:30:0     08/01/2018 15:40:0         3:00:0
    1234  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:50:0         3:00:0
    1234  2   08/02/2018 20:20:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0         3:30:0
    1234  2   08/02/2018 22:50:0     08/02/2018 23:50:0         3:30:0
    1235  1   08/01/2018 11:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0         4:30:0
    5212  1   08/01/2018 14:50:0     08/01/2018 15:20:0         4:30:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `transform`

```
#df[['startdate','enddate']]=df[['startdate','enddate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
g=df.groupby(['cpf' ,'day'])
df['DIFF']=g.enddate.transform('last')-g.startdate.transform('first')
```